# SSMS Addin - GetHierarchy Method Is NULL

Tags: add-in, methodinfo, ssms-2014

I'm writing an addin for SSMS 2014. I want to get hierarchy for search an item in ObjectExplorer.
But GetHierarchy method comes null. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
ObjectExplorerService objExplorerService = (ObjectExplorerService)ServiceCache.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IObjectExplorerService));
MethodInfo getHierarchyMethod = objExplorerService.GetType().GetMethod("GetHierarchy", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer of my question. I accessed "Object Explorer Hierarchy" with the following code.

```
List<IExplorerHierarchy> hierarchyList = new List<IExplorerHierarchy>();
ObjectExplorerService objExplorerService = (ObjectExplorerService)ServiceCache.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IObjectExplorerService));
System.Type t = objExplorerService.GetType();

PropertyInfo getHierarchyMethod = t.GetProperty("Tree", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value = getHierarchyMethod.GetValue(objExplorerService, null);

PropertyInfo getHierarchyMethod2s = value.GetType().GetProperty("Hierarchies", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value2 = getHierarchyMethod2s.GetValue(value, null);

foreach (var item in (Dictionary<string, IExplorerHierarchy>)value2)
{
    hierarchyList.Add(item.Value);
}
```